# How to programmatically activate Context Help Mode on a Windows Form in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, context-sensitive-help

I am building a Windows Forms application in C# (Visual Studio, .net framework 4.7.2).

I have created a form, and set the HelpButton property to True, so that the Context Help button appears on the window's title bar as shown here:

[image]

Under normal circumstances, the user can click this help button, which activates Context Help Mode. Then they click on a control to display context-sensitive help.  (The HelpRequested event is dispatched to the control.)

I want to be able to activate the Context Help Mode using a keyboard shortcut so that the user doesn't have to CLICK the help button on the title bar.  In other words, I need to **programmatically activate Context Help Mode**.  How is this done?

Please understand that I am NOT asking how to open context-sensitive help by pressing a hotkey on a control.  (I.e. press F1 while a control has focus to bring up help about that control).  This is NOT what I want to do.  I want to programmatically activate the **Context Help Mode** (where the cursor turns to a question mark) so that the user can then click on the desired control to get context-sensitive help.)

Forms have the "OnHelpButtonClicked()" function, which is supposed to fire the Help Button clicked event, so I tried the following with no success:

```
CancelEventArgs ee = new CancelEventArgs();
this.OnHelpButtonClicked(ee);
```

How can the Context Help Mode be turned on programmatically without clicking the Help button on the window title bar?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Not a duplicate, but may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392070/how-to-do-context-help-what-is-this-button-in-winforms

Comment: @nilsK This works.  So now I understand: it must be done with a Windows message instead of calling a method within the C# app.  Thank you!  Put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Just was curious ... you made it work. Post your solution and accept it =)

Answer (score 0):

The solution, thanks to @nilsK and the following post: [How to do context help ("what is this?" button) in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392070) requires sending a Windows Message to the form to trigger the Context Help Mode:

In the window's main class:

```
private const int SC_CONTEXTHELP = 0xf180;
private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
```

In the keypress handler or other event to trigger Context Help Mode:

```
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)SC_CONTEXTHELP, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Works!